# Jupyter Notebook Image Captions

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there a simple way of adding captions to images in Jupyter notebooks? I haven't figured out how to do this just yet and was hoping that somebody could give me some direction. So far in my searches I've come across two sources. I wasn't able to get the first, [Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855828/how-to-add-latex-figure-captions-below-jupyter-matplotlib-figures), to work. When I try out that route I don't see a displayed image, but rather the latex code within a closed box like so: [Snapshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCSdS.png)

The other reference that I've come across is [Source 2](http://blog.juliusschulz.de/blog/ultimate-ipython-notebook). This has a description under the "Figures" section which describes how you can insert a caption by editing a cell's metadata. In my version of Jupyter however(version 4.4.0), I don't see any tool bars that would allow me to edit the metadata of an individual cell. Without this capability I'm not sure how to follow the instructions of the given post.

Does anybody have any ideas where I'm going wrong or does anyone know of a simple way to add image captions within Jupyter notebooks? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know about Jupyter version 4.4.0, but in my version 5.7.4 there is an option to add an `Edit Metadata` button to every cell by selecting the following option: View -> Cell Toolbar --> Edit Metadata

Answer (score 2):

This question is super old but here is the general format

```
<figure>
<img src="WHERE THE PHOTO IS STORED" style="width:100%">
<figcaption align = "center"> YOUR CAPTION </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: @ZephaniahGrunschlag It should work, what's the issue?